# Find the unit vector parallel to $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ the angle and the area of a parallelogram shown in the figure below

Tags: vectors

[image]

For context this is what I had computed using the previous parts to the question

13a)

My final vector was in the form of \begin{equation}
19 \underline{i}-6 \underline{j}-7 \underline{k}
\end{equation}

I am writing the final vector in this form due to the formatting of vectors messing up

13b) \begin{equation}
19 \underline{i}-6 \underline{j}-7 \underline{k}
\end{equation}\begin{equation}
\vec{a}=\sqrt{4^{2}+3^{2}+2^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{a}=\sqrt{29}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{b}=\sqrt{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}} \Rightarrow \sqrt{14}
\end{equation}

Therefore my final answer for b was
\begin{equation}
\vec{b}=\sqrt{1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}} \Rightarrow \sqrt{14}
\end{equation}\begin{equation}
\sqrt{29}+\sqrt{14}=|\vec{a}+\vec{b}|
\end{equation}

c)

\begin{equation}
\vec{a}=\frac{4 i-3 j+2 k}{\sqrt{29}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vec{b}=\frac{i+2 j-3 k}{\sqrt{14}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text { let } \vec{r}=\vec{a}+\vec{b}=5 \underline{i}-j-\underline{k}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{R}=\frac{\vec{R}}{|\vec{R}|}
\end{equation}

From this point onwards do we find the magnitude of R and put it in the previous equation? Also from d and e I have no idea where to start and how to tackle the question

Comment: Yes that is correct approach for c. Hint for d and e: Dot and cross product.

Comment: So for c) the magnitude I found was \begin{equation}
3 \sqrt{3}
\end{equation} and therefore \begin{equation}
3 \sqrt{3}
\end{equation}\begin{equation}
\hat{R}=\frac{5 \underline{i}-\underline{j}-\underline{k}}{3 \sqrt{3}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to (a) is $19i-6j-k$

(b) $a+b=5i-j-k$ and $|a+b|=\sqrt{25 +1 +1}=\sqrt{27}=3\sqrt{3}$

(c) $c(a+b)=5c-cj-ck$ and $\sqrt{25c^{2}+c^{2}+c^{2}}=1$ and

$c=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$, so the unit vector parallel to $a+b$ is

$\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}(5i-j-k)$.

(d) By definition $<v,w>=|v||w|cos(v,w)$ so

$cos(a+b,4a+3b)=<5i-j-k,19i-6j-k>\dfrac{1}{|a+b||4a+3b|}$=$(5.19+6+1)\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{3}\,\sqrt{19^{2}+36+1}}$=$\dfrac{102}{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{398}}$

and the angle $(a+b,4a+3b)=cos^{-1}\dfrac{102}{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{398}}$.

To find the area we use the formula

$A=|a\,\times\,b|=\begin{vmatrix}
 i& j & k \\
4 &-3  &2  \\
1 &2  &-3  \\
\end{vmatrix}=|5i+14j+11k|=\sqrt{342}$.

I hope I didn't make any mistakes in my calculations.